# How to get 3rd level Object count in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm building a list of sections, categories and subcategories for a small e-market project on Django.

I have a model like this:

> Section > Category (FK Section) > SubCategory (FK Category) > ShopProduct (FK SubCategory)

The problem is that I have many of categories (and subcategories) which are empty, and for that reason I filter data in the query set with:

`{% if section.shopcategory_set.count > 0 %}`

It will filter the sections if there are more than 1 categories assigned to this section. (But it doesn't filter if any items are assigned deeper)

So, I want to count final objects from the first level cycle

Something like:

```
{% for section in sections %}
    {% if section.category_set.subcategory_set.shopproduct_set.count > 0 %}
    {{ section.name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Doing this will would make your queries a *lot* slower, and the benefits of doing so may well not outweigh this...

Comment: @Sayse i accept it, But I think that Empty link is worse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle is to start from the object you want to retrieve, or in this case count. So, you need to start with ShopProduct and follow the relationships. In a view that would be:

```
ShopProduct.objects.filter(subcategory__category__section=my_section)
```

However, you can't do this in the template, because you can't call methods with parameters. So you'd need to define this as a method on the Section class, replacing `my_section` with `self`, then you can do (eg) `{{ section.get_product_count }}`.

Comment: If I do it your way and then call cycle like {% for product in products %} product.{% endfor %} it will call shop products filtered by the section, Maybe I could not explain my question. The aim is to exclude Empty Section (The section which HAS category, HAS subcategory, but dont have products in sub category)

Comment: Well, you just need to add `.count()` on the end. Does that not work?

Comment: "So you'd need to define this as a method on the Section class, replacing my_section with self" can you show mw how to make that class?

Comment: args['sections'] = ShopSection.objects.all().order_by('name') //// 
args['secprod'] = ShopProduct.objects.filter(shop_product_category__category__section = self) ///// returns "global name 'self' is not defined"

Comment: I said you should write a method on the model class - ie `def get_product_count(self): return ShopProduct...`

Comment: IN My models.py --- def get_product_count(self):
 return ShopProduct.objects.filter(shop_product_category__category__section = self) /// in my views --- args['sections'] = ShopSection.objects.all().order_by('name') //// in template {% for section in sections %} {{ section.name }} {{section.get_product_count.count }} {% endfor %} === NO EFFECTS :-(